# Change return value if Select statement returns nothing

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to change the return value of the Select statement. I need to do it in SQL.
Say, we have

```
SELECT CourseCode FROM Course WHERE CourseName='?' -- '?' refers to user value
```

If the user value is null or if the course name is not in the database, I would like the select statement to return 'Not applicable'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT CourseCode FROM Course WHERE CourseName='?'

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Not Applicable'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT CourseCode FROM Course WHERE CourseName='?'
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT IFNULL(Course.CourseCode,'Not applicable') AS CourseCode
FROM (SELECT 1) AS dummy
LEFT JOIN Course ON CourseName='?'
```

Comment: Thank u sir. I felt that Michael's answer was better as i understood it better.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function IFNULL() where you can decide what the query return if the value is null, but it's not after the WHERE